# Passing HTML to Template within Django

Tags: django

I have a list being passed to my template. However I want to 3rd item to be href`d. 
If i add the html in the view and pass it to the template it get escaped and displayed as html rather then a link.

Whats the best way to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) in your template to conditionally add the href rather than trying to add HTML in the view:

template.html

```
<ul>
{% for item in mylist %}
    <li>
        {% if forloop.counter == 3 %}<a href="myhref">{% endif %}{{ item }}{% if forloop.counter == 3 %}</a>{% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `autoscape` tag or the `safe` filter, see the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-safe) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape).

Take in mind that can be dangerous to allow rendering of HTML directly if the data come from untrusted source.